# Fixing memory leaks without changing values

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

So, I made a stacklibrary that can have multiple stacks in a linked list . Each stack can have objects as a linked list. I tested the program and it worked but I have memory leaks that i can't seem to fix. I tried doing it with tutorials and everything but when I try it, it either changes the values inside my lists or it doesn't work. Can someone show me? Code:

EDIT:
This is all the code I use, I run the tests with unity. I use Valgrind to detect memory leaks. I do the valgrind command on these tests. I just tried to clear a stack but got a double free or corruption error

Comment: How are you determining there are memory leaks?  If a tool is telling you this, please tell us the tool and show us the output; if it's valgrind, it often includes actionable information.

Comment: `mystack_destroy` doesn't try to `free` the contents of the stack being destroyed.

Comment: There is definitely some problem in `mystack_destroy` It is currently dereferencing `tmpStackList` after it has been freed. How much testing have you done? I think `mystack_destroy` should probably be removing a stack from `gStackList`, which it is not doing correctly.

Comment: It's better to use tools to debug memory leak. Can you post code that can compile?

Comment: I only ran the first test with valgrind so only use mystack_create and get invalid read or write on all the times I read or write a newStackList->... value. From where i malloc newStackList

Comment: regarding: `#include "unity.h"`  the contents of that header file are not posted.  The result is the posted code does not compile

Comment: regarding: `pStackObject_t newStack = malloc(sizeof(pStackObject_t));`  The function: `malloc()` can fail.  Therefore, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `int main ( int argc, char * argv[] )`  since those parameters are never used, the compiler will output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `extern int mystack_create( size_t objsize ) ;` and similar statements.  Functions are always extern, unless they have the `static` modifier.  So the modifier `extern` is not needed and just clutters the code

Comment: regarding: `__MYSTACK_H__`  in general, two leading underscores are 'reserved' for the implementation and should not be getting defined in user code.  Suggest: `MYSTACK_H`

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct stackObject* pStackObject_t;`  it is a very poor programming practice to hide pointers in `typedef` statements

Answer (score 0):

Size of area allocation no fit space for some struct.
Change in mystack_create:

```
  pStackMeta_t newStackList = malloc(sizeof(pStackMeta_t));
to
  pStackMeta_t newStackList = malloc(sizeof(StackMeta_t));
```

newStackList->stack = malloc(sizeof(pStackObject_t));
to
  newStackList->stack = malloc(sizeof(StackObject_t));

Chamge in mystack_push:

```
  pStackObject_t newStack = malloc(sizeof(pStackObject_t));
to
  pStackObject_t newStack = malloc(sizeof(StackObject_t));
```

Comment: good advise, but doesn't get rid of the memory leaks due to not passing the allocated memory pointers to `free()`

Answer (score 0):

regarding the memory leaks:

For every pointer returned from a call to `malloc()` or `calloc()` there must be a call to `free()` with that same pointer value.

this code:

```
while( tmpStackList != NULL && tmpStackList->handle != handle ) 
{
    tmpStackList = tmpStackList->next;
    if( tmpStackList == NULL ) 
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

is failing to pass all those allocated memory chunks to `free()`